# Admob banner is not displayed

Tags: java, android

i have tried to integrate an Admob banner to my app in android studio, but is not displayed.

I did it like this:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

The code is:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.us.aspirationindex"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
```

}

**string.xml**

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">Aspiration Index</string>
<string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
<string name="mainwelcome">Find out what really motivates you in your life</string>



<!--eng  Dimentions -->
<array name="engDimentions">
    <item>Personal growth</item>
    <item>Affiliation</item>
    <item>Community involvement</item>
    <item>Physical fitness</item>
    <item>Wealth</item>
    <item>Fame</item>
    <item>Image</item>
</array>
<!--eng  Dimentions -->

<!--deu  Dimentions -->
<array name="deuDimentions">
    <item>Persönliches Wachstum</item>
    <item>Beziehungen</item>
    <item>Gesellschaft</item>
    <item>Gesundheit</item>
    <item>Wohlstand</item>
    <item>Wohlstand</item>
    <item>Attraktivität</item>
</array>
<!--deu  Dimentions -->


<!-- eng traits -->
<array name="eng0">
    <item>To grow and learn new things</item>
    <item>At the end of my life, to be able to look back on my life as meaningful and complete
    </item>
    <item>To choose what I do, instead of being pushed along by life</item>
    <item>To know and accept who I really am</item>
    <item>To gain increasing insight into why I do the things I do</item>
</array>
<array name="eng1">
    <item>To have good friends that I can count on</item>
    <item>To share my life with someone I love</item>
    <item>To have committed, intimate relationships</item>
    <item>To feel that there are people who really love me, and whom I love</item>
    <item>To have deep, enduring relationships</item>
</array>
<array name="eng2">
    <item>To work for a better society</item>
    <item>To assist people who need it, asking nothing in return</item>
    <item>To work to make the world a better place</item>
    <item>To help others improve their lives</item>
    <item>To help people in need</item>
</array>
<array name="eng3">
    <item>To be physically healthy</item>
    <item>To feel good about my level of physical fitness</item>
    <item>To keep myself healthy and well</item>
    <item>To be relatively free from sickness</item>
    <item>To have a physically healthy lifestyle</item>
</array>
<array name="eng4">
    <item>To be a very wealthy person</item>
    <item>To have many expensive possessions</item>
    <item>To be financially successful</item>
    <item>To be rich</item>
    <item>To have enough money to buy everything I want</item>
</array>
<array name="eng5">
    <item>To have my name known by many people</item>
    <item>To be admired by many people</item>
    <item>To be famous</item>
    <item>To have my name appear frequently in the media</item>
    <item>To be admired by lots of different people</item>
</array>
<array name="eng6">
    <item>To successfully hide signs of aging</item>
    <item>To have people comment often about how attractive I look</item>
    <item>To keep up with fashions in hair and clothing</item>
    <item>To achieve the “look” I’ve been after</item>
    <item>To have an image that others find appealing</item>
</array>

<!-- eng traits -->


<!-- due traits -->
<array name="deu0">
    <item>Meine Persönlichkeit entwickeln und Neues lernen</item>
    <item>Am Ende meines Lebens dieses als sinnvoll und komplett betrachten können</item>
    <item>Selbst entscheiden, was ich tue und lasse, anstatt Zwängen des Lebens zu folgen</item>
    <item>Wissen, wer ich bin und mich annehmen</item>
    <item>Mich selbst und mein Handeln besser verstehen</item>
</array>

<array name="deu1">
    <item>Gute Freunde haben, auf die ich mich verlassen kann</item>
    <item>Mein Leben mit jemanden teilen, den ich liebe</item>
    <item>Eine feste, innige Beziehung führen</item>
    <item>Fühlen, dass es Menschen gibt, die mich lieben und die ich liebe</item>
    <item>Tiefe und beständige Beziehungen führen</item>
</array>

<array name="deu2">
    <item>Zu einer besseren Gesellschaft beitragen</item>
    <item>Menschen helfen, die Unterstützung brauchen ohne eine Gegenleistung zu erwarten
    </item>
    <item>Dazu beitragen, die Welt zu verbessern</item>
    <item>Anderen helfen, ihr Leben zu verbessern</item>
    <item>Menschen in Not helfen</item>
</array>

<array name="deu3">
    <item>Körperlich gesund sein</item>
    <item>Mit meiner körperlichen Fitness zufrieden sein</item>
    <item>Mich selbst gesund und in guter Form halten</item>
    <item>Von Krankheiten verschont bleiben</item>
    <item>Einen gesunden Lebensstil pflegen</item>
</array>

<array name="deu4">
    <item>Eine sehr reiche Person sein</item>
    <item>Viele teure Dinge besitzen</item>
    <item>Finanziell erfolgreich sein</item>
    <item>Reich sein</item>
    <item>Genug Geld haben, um alles zu kaufen, was ich will</item>
</array>

<array name="deu5">
    <item>Vielen Menschen bekannt sein</item>
    <item>Von vielen Menschen bewundert werden</item>
    <item>Berühmt sein</item>
    <item>Häufig in den Medien erwähnt werden</item>
    <item>Von vielen verschiedenen Personen bewundert werden</item>
</array>

<array name="deu6">
    <item>Erfolgreich die Spuren des Alterns verbergen</item>
    <item>Häufig Komplimente wegen meines Aussehens bekommen</item>
    <item>Bei Trends auf dem Laufenden bleiben</item>
    <item>So auszusehen, wie ich es immer wollte</item>
    <item>So aussehen, dass es auf andere anziehend wirkt</item>
</array>
<string name="title_activity_main"></string>
<string name="title_activity_explanation"></string>
<string name="engExplaination">Below you will find a number of life goals, presented one at a time. Please use the corresponding scale to answer this questions.</string>
<string name="deuExplaination">Im Folgenden werden Ihnen einige Lebensziele präsentiert. Bitte geben Sie auf der dazugehörigen Antwortskala an wie wichtig Ihnen das jeweilige Lebensziel ist.</string>
<string name="title_activity_question_answers"></string>
<string name="title_activity_forth_screen"></string>
<string name="engForthScreenText">Personal goals are desired states and describes the important things for a Person in life. There are two classes of goals – intrinsic and extrinsic goals. Intrinsic goals are determined through basic human needs. Extrinsic goals depend on the reactions of other people. This test gives you an idea which goals are important for you.</string>
<string name="deuForthScreenText">Persönliche Ziele sind erwünschte Zustände und beschreiben was einer Person im Leben wichtig ist. Es werden zwei Inhaltsklassen von Zielen – intrinsische und extrinsische Ziele –  unterschieden. Intrinsische Ziele werden von grundlegenden menschlichen Bedürfnissen beeinflusst.  Extrinsische Ziele sind abhängig von den Reaktionen anderer Personen. Dieser Test gibt Ihnen eine Vorstellung davon, welche Ziele Ihnen wichtig sind.</string>
<string name="title_activity_fifth_screen"></string>
<string name="engFifthScreenTitle">Intrinsic Goals</string>
<string name="deuFifthScreenTitle">Intrinsische Ziele</string>
<string name="deuFifthScreenText">Persönliches Wachstum: \n•\tAutonomie, Selbstachtung und persönliches Wachstum erreichen    \n\nBeziehungen: \n•\tBefriedigende Beziehungen zu Familie und Freunden aufbauen  \n\nGesellschaft: \n•\tDie Welt durch aktives Handeln verbessern und sich um zukünftige Genrationen kümmern   \n\nGesundheit: \n•\tSich fit fühlen und frei von Krankheiten sein</string>
<string name="engFifthScreenText">Personal growth: \n•\tArchive psychological growth, autonomy and self-regard  \n\nAffiliation: \n•\tHave satisfying relationshps with famaly and freinds  \n\nCommunity involvement: \n•\tImprove the world through activities or generativity  \n\nPhysical fitness: \n•\tFeel healthy and free of illness</string>
<string name="title_activity_sixth_screen"></string>
<string name="deuSixthScreenTitle">Extrinsische Ziele</string>
<string name="deuSixthScreenText">Wohlstand: \n•\tAnhäufen von Reichtümern und finanziell erfolgreich sein  \n\nRuhm: \n•\tBekannt und berühmt sein und von anderen bewundert werden  \n\nAttraktivität: \n•\tSich attraktiv fühlen hinsichtlich Körper und Bekleidung</string>
<string name="engSixthScreenTitle">Extrinsic Goals</string>
<string name="engSixthScreenText">Wealth: \n•\tBe wealthy and martially successful  \n\nFame: \n•\tBe famous, well-known and admired  \n\nImage: \n•\tLook attractive in terms of body, clothing and fashion</string>
<string name="title_activity_seventh_screen"></string>
<string name="engSeventhScreenText">For Aspiration Index the following guidelines exists</string>
<string name="deuSeventhScreenText">Für den Aspiration Index existieren folgende Richtwerte</string>
<string name="engSeventhScreenLow">Low</string>
<string name="engSeventhScreenAverage">Average</string>
<string name="engSeventhScreenHigh">High</string>
<string name="SeventhScreenLowValue">• 1 to 2.4</string>
<string name="SeventhScreenAverageValue">• 2.5 to 3.5</string>
<string name="SeventhScreenHighValue">• 3.6 to 5</string>
<string name="deuSeventhScreenLow">Niedrig</string>
<string name="deuSeventhScreenAverage">Durchschnittlich</string>
<string name="dueSeventhScreenHigh">Hoch</string>
<string name="title_activity_result"></string>

<!-- due traits -->
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.us.aspirationindex.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<!--android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" /-->

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btneng,btndue;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
    btneng= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEng);
    btndue= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonDeu);
    btneng.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Constants.langkey=Constants.English;
            InitializeTrails();
        }
    });
    btndue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Constants.langkey=Constants.Duetsch;
            InitializeTrails();

        }
    });
}

private void InitializeTrails() {
    ArrayList<String> temp=new ArrayList<String>();
    if(Constants.langkey.equals(Constants.English)) {

        //dimentions
        Constants.dimentionsArrayList.clear();
        Constants.dimentionsArrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.engDimentions)));
        //dimentions

        //traits

        Constants.traitsArrayList.clear();

        temp.clear();
        temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.eng0)));
        for (String trait:temp) {
            Constants.traitsArrayList.add(new Trait(1,trait));
        }

        temp.clear();
        temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.eng1)));
        for (String trait:temp) {
            Constants.traitsArrayList.add(new Trait(2,trait));
        }

        temp.clear();
        temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.eng2)));
        for (String trait:temp) {
            Constants.traitsArrayList.add(new Trait(3,trait));
        }

        temp.clear();
        temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.eng3)));
        for (String trait:temp) {
            Constants.traitsArrayList.add(new Trait(4,trait));
        }

        temp.clear();
        temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.eng4)));
        for (String trait:temp) {
            Constants.traitsArrayList.add(new Trait(5,trait));
        }

        temp.clear();
        temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.eng5)));
        for (String trait:temp) {
            Constants.traitsArrayList.add(new Trait(6,trait));
        }

        temp.clear();
        temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.eng6)));
        for (String trait:temp) {
            Constants.traitsArrayList.add(new Trait(7,trait));
        }

        //traits
    }
    else
    {

        //dimentions
        Constants.dimentionsArrayList.clear();
        Constants.dimentionsArrayList.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.deuDimentions)));
        //dimentions

        //traits

        Constants.traitsArrayList.clear();

        temp.clear();
        temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.deu0)));
        for (String trait:temp) {
            Constants.traitsArrayList.add(new Trait(1,trait));
        }

        temp.clear();
        temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.deu1)));
        for (String trait:temp) {
            Constants.traitsArrayList.add(new Trait(2,trait));
        }

        temp.clear();
        temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.deu2)));
        for (String trait:temp) {
            Constants.traitsArrayList.add(new Trait(3,trait));
        }

        temp.clear();
        temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.deu3)));
        for (String trait:temp) {
            Constants.traitsArrayList.add(new Trait(4,trait));
        }

        temp.clear();
        temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.deu4)));
        for (String trait:temp) {
            Constants.traitsArrayList.add(new Trait(5,trait));
        }

        temp.clear();
        temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.deu5)));
        for (String trait:temp) {
            Constants.traitsArrayList.add(new Trait(6,trait));
        }

        temp.clear();
        temp.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.deu6)));
        for (String trait:temp) {
            Constants.traitsArrayList.add(new Trait(7,trait));
        }

        //traits
    }
    Collections.shuffle(Constants.traitsArrayList);
    Constants.Limit=Constants.traitsArrayList.size();
    startActivity(new Intent(this,ExplanationActivity.class));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1' compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'

I think the compile version was updated to 9.0.0 for firebase.  And don't forget the plugin that follows the version code. That may help